# Android Studio: App in emulator not showing updated code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-gradle-plugin

So in my Android Studio Project, when I click "Run" for the first time, the app gets deployed to the emulator after a few minutes. Then when I change my code and click "Run" again, the app loads on the emulator (within seconds) but it doesn't show anything I updated.

So what I basically have to do is uninstall the app on the emulator and click on "run" again. It works but the problem with this is that it takes 4-5 minutes to deploy the app to emulator. It says "gradle build running" and it finishes after 4-5 minutes and I can't wait that long every time I change my code. So how can I make it so that when I click "run", it shows updated code so I don't have to keep uninstalling the app.

Comment: try to clean your project

Comment: which version of android studio are you using? if it is above 2.0, the  "instant run" feature would give u such a problem. if that were the case, stop the application from android studio and then force stop the application on the device. now try re-running the application from android studio. it should provide you with the appropriate code changes.